# Materialize accordion don't work in Algolia template

Tags: jquery, materialize, algolia

i'm trying to put the description of a product gain with Algolia in a Materialize's accordion and it doesn't trigger when i click on it.

Here's the code in my view:

```
    <div class="row">
     <div id="hits-container"></div>
    </div>

 <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/instantsearch.js/1/instantsearch.min.js"></script>
 <script src="<?php echo js_url('jquery.min')?>"></script>
 <script src="<?php echo js_url('initialization')?>"></script>
 <script src="<?php echo js_url('pluginAlgolia')?>"></script>
 <script src="<?php echo js_url('materialize.min')?>"></script>
 <script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
   $('select').material_select();
   $('.collapsible').collapsible();
  });
 </script>
```

Here is the code for the hits widgets in pluginAlgolia.js:

```
search.addWidget(
 instantsearch.widgets.hits({
  container: '#hits-container',
  hitsPerPage: 6,
  templates: {
    empty: noResultsTemplate,
    item: hitTemplate
   }
  })
 );
```

And here's the template in initialization.js:

```
var hitTemplate =
 '<div class="col s12 m6 l4">' +
  '<article class="hit">' +
   '<div class="product-picture-wrapper center">' +
    '<div class="product-picture"><img src="{{image}}" /></div>' +
   '</div>' +
   '<div class="product-name"><h4>{{{_highlightResult.designation.value}}}</h4></div>' +
     '<ul class="collapsible" data-collapsible="accordion">' +
      '<li>'+
        '<div class="collapsible-header">Description</div>' +
        '<div class="collapsible-body">' +
          '{{{_highlightResult.description.value}}}' +
        '</div>' +
       '</li>' +
      '</ul>' +
     '<div class="product-price">${{prixttc}}</div>' +
    '</article>' +
   '</div>';
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your call to `.collapsible()` only happens when the DOM has been fully loaded for the first time.

However, each time `instantsearch.js` renders your template, it adds to the DOM new elements on which `.collapsible()` has never been called.

You can however use `instantsearch.js`'s [`render` event](https://community.algolia.com/instantsearch.js/documentation/#events), to call `.collapsible()` on these newly created DOM elements :

```
search.on('render', function () {
  $('.collapsible').collapsible();
});
```

This will also call `.collapsible()` on elements on which it has already been called. I don't know `collapsible`, its behaviour might be wrong if you call it twice on the same element.
To avoid this, you'll want to target only elements on which it hasn't been called. `collapsible` might add an attribute or a class on those DOM elements, that you can exclude in the selector.
Otherwise you could simply add it yourself like this:

```
search.on('render', function () {
  $('.collapsible:not(.collapsible-called)').collapsible().addClass('collapsible-called');
});
```